# Adding item to view programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to find out how I can add an item (from xml drawable/workaround_item.xml) in a LinearLayout that is vertically aligned.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dip"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
  android:paddingTop="5dip"
  android:paddingBottom="5dip"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">            
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/home_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />           
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_team" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>          
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/game_cship" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>               
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/game_score" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff" android:textSize="24sp"/>          
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/game_date" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>           
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">                       
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/away_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />           
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/away_team" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />     
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

At the beginning I was trying to use a ListView but as far I as know there is a bug using listview inside a scrollview. I was doing this because I have more components on the view that should be scrolled together with the list view. So I decided to remove the listview and implement a simple linear layout where i will be adding each element below other and so on.

The layout for the activity is as follow (layout/workaround.xml) and I would like to start adding the elements below the top bar.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    
android:id="@+id/linearid" >

</LinearLayout>
```

That's my Java code:

```
public class DemoActivity3 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workaround);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearid);

    for(int i = 1; i< 15; i++) {        
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workaround_item, null);
        TextView x = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.game_score);
        x.setText("Score" + i);
        TextView ht = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.home_team);
        ht.setText("HomeTeam" + i);
        TextView at = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.away_team);
        at.setText("AwayTeam"+i);
        ImageView hi = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.home_image);
        hi.setImageResource(R.drawable.gremio);
        ImageView ai = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.away_image);
        ai.setImageResource(R.drawable.goias);
        ll.addView(item,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

That's the result I am getting: http://twitpic.com/3562yu

Does Android allow us to do this? If so, Hoe can I add the elements and set their values? (this layout will be displaying results of soccer games).

Comment: Please post the full XML for your "workaround_item" - what you've posted is invalid XML as you have three LinearLayouts that are not contained in anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to create an instance of an xml layout file.

Then just call [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) on your LinearLayout.

Comment: I am inflating my item and adding it 15 times to the linear layout. However, i only see the first one right in the middle of the screen. I was trying to get the "list" of items in the screen, but no success.

Comment: You added the same item 15 times?  You need to create 15 different objects and add them..

Comment: Thats what i am doing. I have a loop for 15 elements and I am adding them. I am trying to paste my code here in the comment section, but no way.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question with additional details.

Comment: Done. I edited my question adding the java code and the result, as you can see, i see only one result instead of 15.

Comment: It looks ok.. what if you remove the layout params as the second into to addView?  You might also take a look at hierarchy viewer (in the tools directory) to see if the views are showing up somewhere wierd.

Comment: I open the hierarchy view and no device is listed. My emulator is up and running. Removing the layout parameters didnt change anything, same result.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "bug" about ListView in ScrollView, this is just nonsense.

There's a feature in ListView that allow you to add [header](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)/[footer](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) views which would allow you to place anything above and below the regular items of your ListView.

Comment: Sorry for saying "bug" but I have seen a lot of threads/posts saying to not use listview inside a header view. Is there any sample code available for adding header to a listview? Thanks

Comment: Buy the way, the header will not scroll along with the list itens.

Comment: So you just need to define a vertical linear layout containing your Header and then a ListView.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin said you're better to use a list view with a header. The header will scroll with the list.

However if you're programatically adding views to a layout, you're code should work. Try adding them with a LayoutParam object:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(item, params);
```